# Scanner Input: Throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: nosuchelementexception

Why does Java accept 1234567891 as input but not 987654321 ?
I keep getting NoSuchElementException, and I am just wondering why the error.

Comment: Post the code here

Answer (score 2):

Range of 4 byte integer in Java is 
`–2,147,483,648` to  `2,147,483,647`

Thus it won't be able to accept `987654321` in `scanner.getInt();`

To accept the above mentioned value , use `scanner.getLong()`

Comment: use scanner.getlong()

Comment: Its all given in javadocs please go through that first before posting the problems